# Can't get trendlines to work

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/b8e8t/1/

I wasn't able to get the fiddle to work by splitting the JS and the HTML, so I just left it in the HTML window.

Check the console when loading this fiddle, it will show 2 errors:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M0.5,-3.879860269285669e+59L11.599999999999........
```

The offending part is:

```
var options = {"title": "User activity","theme": "maximized","width": 1000,"height": 500,"trendlines": "2: {color: 'purple'}"};
```

Specifically the trendlines part. I cannot for the live of me figure out why the trendlines don't work, the data looks alright to me.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was wrong. I used the PHP wrapper `Chart.php` and it was outputting data from Mysql as strings, not as integers. Casting the data as `int` solved the issue. Apparently  Google Charts is very stingy about data types.

Comment: That would indeed cause problems.  If your wrapper is using the `json_encode` function, there is a shortcut that you can use rather than typecasting all of your database outputs: add `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` as an argument to the `json_encode` call: `json_encode($myData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: Another great tip. Thanks, I had been looking at those, but hadn't realized that would do the trick. All tough typecasting feels a bit cleaner.

Comment: PHP is so loosely typed that typecasting is almost a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for adding a trendline is wrong.  The `trendlines` option is an object, not a string.  Also, you must specify the type of trendline (`'linear'` or `'exponential'`).  It should look like this:

```
trendlines: {
    // trendline for the first data series (patients)
    0: {
        type: 'exponential',
        color: 'purple'
    }
}
```

Also, you should only use one callback from the google loader (multiple callbacks are not supported).  Create a function that calls your draw functions and pass that as the callback:

```
function init () {
    drawChart1();
    drawChart2();
    drawChart3();
}
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart'],'language': 'en', callback: init});
```

Comment: Upvote because you are totally right, but it's not the answer. See below.